# Blazor WASM RuntimeError memory out of bounds

Tags: asp.net, .net, runtime-error, blazor, webassembly

I am working on a Blazor WebAssembly Project and since today everytime I debug the application the same error appears:

[image]

I cannot provide any more details at the moment since I don't know how to drill down this error. I already looked at several similar questions and answers, but none of them applied to my specific problem.

I am grateful for any suggestion on how to debug or even resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you please show your code... you may be suffering from a circular reference

Comment: what part in particular? it is a large project already

Comment: okay i will try that, however it is quite hard since debugging does not work properly in blazor wasm. atleast in my project breakpoints won't get hit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found my (silly) mistake. Like enet and many other people in previous questions stated, I suffered from a circular reference.

In particular I have a custom AuthenticationProvider in which I inject a custom HttpClient.

Stupid me injected the AuthProvider also in the custom Client, so that was my issue.